# Roots of a $p$-polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $F$ be of characteristic $p$. A polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ is called a $p$-polynomial if it has the form $x^{p^m}+a_1x^{p^{m-1}}+\cdots+a_mx$. Show that a monic polynomial of positive degree is a $p$-polynomial iff its roots form a finite subgroup of the additive group of the splitting field, and every root has the same multiplicity $p^e$. [*Basic Algebra I*, by Nathan Jacobson. (3 pp. 234.)]

I need help on the $\Longleftarrow$ direction for the simpler case when all roots are simple.

Someone hinted me to consider the polynomial $f(x+a)$ for every root $a$, so far I can only conclude that $f(x+a)=f(x)=f(x)+f(a)$. How can I use this to show $f(x)$ is a $p$-polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us fix a splitting field $K$ for $f$. Let $a \in K$ be a root of $f$. Then every root of $f$ is a root of $f(X+a)$, and $f$ is separable so $f|f(X+a)$. Since both polynomials are monic of the same degree, $f(X+a)=f$.

Now, consider $g(Y)=f(X+Y)-f(X) \in F(X)[Y]$. Then $g$ is monic with the degree of $f$ and if $y \in K$ is a root of $f$, then $g(y)=0$. As $f$ is separable, $f(Y)|g(Y)$, and thus $f(X+Y)=f(X)+f(Y)$.

So now, we show that a polynomial $f$ over a field $F$ of characteristic $p$ such that $f(X+Y)=f(X)+f(Y)$ must be a linear combination of the $X^{p^i}$.

Indeed, if it isn’t the case, we can subtract from $f$ a linear combination of the $X^{p^i}$ so that $f(X)=\alpha X^t+O(X^{t-1})$ with $\alpha \neq 0$ and $t$ not a power of $p$.

Then $0=f(X+Y)-f(X)-f(Y)=\alpha\sum_{k=1}^{t-1}{\binom{t}{k}X^kY^{t-k}}+\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}{O(X^kY^{t-1-k})}$. Thus for each $1 \leq k < t$, $p|\binom{t}{k}$. This forces $t$ to be a power of $p$.